# How to get the tableview object which is inside a tab which inturn is inside a Tabpane Javafx

Tags: javafx, tabs, javafx-2, tabpanel

I have a tabpane which has 13 tabs and each of those thirteen tabs have 13 table views as well as some components like buttons and labels in each tab

I want to get the tableview object by selecting the tableview from a particular tab.
Like if the focus comes to a table view i can get to know from which tab it has come so that i can use the particular tableview object in a method.

As i  have a method that will do a task which is same just the tableview changes depending upon the tab , si if i can get the tableviews i do not need to code 13 methods. But the issue is the tab on tabpane dosent only have tableview it has labels buttons also. How to fetch the extact I am not sure how to move further as beacuse what i exactly want is like i have a method that will do a task which ia same just the tableview changes depending upon the tab , so if  i can get the tableview obj  of each tab  i do not need to code 13 methods. But the issue is the tab on tabpane dosent only have tableview it has labels buttons also. How to fetch the extact node.

The logic behind the tab and tab pane is a fxml component . I am using fxml component to develop my application.

eg:-

```
Set<Report> selection = new HashSet<Report>(businessEventReport.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems());
```

here the businessEventreport is a table view in a table , i want to get the particular tableview by focusing on the particular tableview of the tab.

how do i do that .

i can get the tabs using

```
   SingleSelectionModel<Tab> selectionModel = tabpane.getSelectionModel();
   selectionModel.getSelectedItem().getContent();
```

but i am stuck after that.

Comment: It seems that you are doing it right.The ' getContent(); ' returns you a TableView.

Comment: I am not sure how to move further as beacuse what i  exactly want is like i have a method that will do a task which ia same just the tableview changes depending upon the tab , si if i can get the tableviews i do not need to code 13 methods. But the issue is the tab on tabpane dosent only have tableview it has labels buttons also. How to fetch thw extact node.

Comment: Hm that was not mentioned in the question.So every tab contains a layout which contains several controls including and a TableView.Each tab layout is made using fxml or plain java code?I mean the logic behind every tab is a class that has the layout (or extends it) and its components?

Comment: Sorryi will update the question right away , as i thought if i get one component i can get all, the logic behind each class is a fxml component.

Comment: What you can do is add a method in the class which represents fxml controller.For example ´getTableView();´ then when you get the content from the Tab you actually getting an fxml controller.For example the class ´IController´.You can call its method ´ getTableView(); ´and you have what you need.If you need more detailed answer i can write one as soon as i get to a computer :).

Comment: But all i have is a single controller for this tabpane. All these tab and their corresponding tableviews and buttons are there in a single controller,i have not made multiple controllers for multiple tabs . All tabs share the same controller.

Comment: The application has to be like this:One controller  class for the `TabPane`,one controller class for the `Content` of each `Tab` in the `TabPane`(for example `TabContentController` which maybe or maybe not extend The Layout you want),then you create instances of the second controller and you can have a method in the `TabContentController` which when you call it returns the `TableView`.

Comment: Will it not work for the application i already have coded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution would be to assign each of your TableViews an identifier. This 
identifier would then be used to discover the TableView from amongst the set of controls on each tab (or the whole Scene) using the lookup method.

To set the identifier for each TableView use the [Node.setId method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#setId-java.lang.String-).

```
tableView.setId("MyTable")
```

To find the TableView from the TabPane use the [Node.lookup method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#lookup-java.lang.String-).

```
Tab selectedTab = tabPane.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem()
Node selectedContent = selectedTab.getContent()
TableView selectedTable = selectedContent.lookup("#MyTable")
```

The lookup method searches through the children of the Node used to perform the lookup. This gives you the flexibility to either assign each of your TableViews a unique identifier, allowing lookup from TabPane itself or to assign them all the same identifier and use the parent Tab to discover the TableView (example above).

The lookup method uses a CSS selector to find controls so identifiers aren't mandatory. An alternative approach would be to use the class type and state of the TabPane and TableView to form a selector. Something like the following (untested).

```
selectedContent.lookup(".tab-pane > .tab:selected > .table-view")
```

Comment: great Blair saved my LOC, just one Tweak you have to add a TypeCast over there
like
TableView selectedTable = (TableView)selectedContent.lookup("#MyTable")

Thank you, This is what i was looking for